# métodos de inyección de DLL en C#

Tags: c#, dependencias

Hola estoy aprendiendo sobre patrones de diseño orientado a objetos y uno de los temas que mas me intrigan son los metodos de inyeccion de dependencias.

Pero hasta el momento no se exactamente cuales son los metodos mas usados para esta inyeccion.

> Cuales son los metodos mas recomendables?

Por otra parte,

> cuando se hace una inyeccion de una depedencia como se hace para
>   llamar funciones de la misma. Ya que la inyeccion de dependencia no es
>   mas que incluir extensiones a nuestros programas determinados pero no
>   llamadas al mismo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día,

> En informática, inyección de dependencias (en inglés Dependency
>   Injection, DI) es un patrón de diseño orientado a objetos, en el que
>   se suministran objetos a una clase en lugar de ser la propia clase
>   quien cree el objeto. El término fue acuñado por primera vez por
>   Martin Fowler.

Después, [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dn602529.aspx) te dejo un poco de información desde MSDN, [la estrategia](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dn602530.aspx) para desarrollar en C# inyección de dependencia y finalmente unos [ejemplos](http://anexsoft.com/p/97/ejemplo-de-inyeccion-de-dependencias-con-c). Es un tema muy amplio la verdad y abarcarlo todo sería muy complejo, pero espero y te ayude la información que te brindo

Comment: esto seria un ejemplo de inyeccion de dependencia el ejemplo es mio https://youtu.be/5eooo8LcM5Q La cuestion es el programa principal aunque se le incluya esa dependencia tiene que ser capaz de llamar los metodos de la dependencia es basicamente lo que intentaba saber pero tu informacion me va a resultar muy util gracias

Comment: Entonces podrías replantear la pregunta o abrir una nueva pregunta, mostrando ejemplos de tu código y detallando el problema específico. Espero de igual manera te pueda servir la información que te he brindado y espero encuentres la respuesta a tu problema.